# Selenium capybara check background color of a div within another div

Tags: html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, rspec, capybara

I have a `div` with an `id` which contains a div with no `id` but it has a `class`. No the issue is,I want to check the background color of the second `div`. Your help is welcome.

```
<div id = "wrapper">
<div class="container iframe-container">

        <style>
           body { background-color: #000111; } .form-horizontal .control-label { font-style: normal; } ...
        </style>
```

basically I want to check if the background is `#000111`

Comment: I am guessing you didn't see my answer @jeffC

Comment: I saw your answer but you didn't mark it as accepted. Marking it as accepted marks this question as answered. It's as easy as clicking accept below.

Comment: oh alright thanks for the hint, I new to this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finally found the answer:

```
within_frame('wrapper') do
   color = find('body').native.css_value('background-color')
   expect(color).to eq('rgba(0, 1, 17, 1)')
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `background-color` property of `css` to verify the same. First you have to identify the `WebElement` and then use this property on top of it.

```
browser.find_element(:xpath, "Relevant Xpath").style('background-color')
```

Comment: Ok, it tried that it didn't work, plus I am just getting to know `xpaths` not sure I really know how it works. But I have updated the question. More suggestions please. @pArAs

Comment: It won't work as the element is inside `iFrame`. Here in this case, first you have to switch to the frame and then identify the element. You can read about how to switch `frames` using `Selenium`

Comment: thanks for the hint, it made me move forward in a totally different direction and  I have found the answer.